# Get image via ctx.drawImage and convert to base64

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I would like to get image from faviconkit.com in base64. `Fetch` & `XHR` does not work due to Cors. The only think which works is `ctx.drawImage`. Any other JS based methods could help too. Thanks

Here is what I have so far:

```js
const img = new Image();
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const base64 = document.getElementById('base64');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

img.onload = () => {
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 32,32);
};


img.src = "https://api.faviconkit.com/google.com/32";

base64.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + dataURL + "')";
```

```css
#base64 {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="32" height="32"></canvas>

<div id="base64"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/on8krzub/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to call `canvas.toDataURL()` after loading the image. Second, without `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` you won’t be able to convert remote image to data URI.

Therefore, you have some ways to solve your problem:

- Load images via a local Web proxy or a remote one that adds CORS
  headers.
- Contact the FaviconKit owner and suggest him to add the CORS
  headers.
- Use another API that supports requests from any origin. For example: https://favicon.yandex.net/favicon/google.com?size=32

However, even if the remote image returns the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, you cannot call `canvas.toDataURL()` unless you specify `img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'`.

By the way, I do not know if it matters to you, but you must remember that `canvas.toDataURL()` does not return the original Base64 string. In any case, for some additional thoughts and examples, [check this page](https://base64.guru/developers/javascript/examples/convert-image).